# Analogues of Wicks/Isserlis theorem to distributions without 4th order interactions?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, quantum-field-theory

Suppose I have a zero-centered random variable $x\in \mathcal{D}^n$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is either $\{-1,1\}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, and its density has the following form in Einstein notation convention and symmetric tensor $M$

$$\log p(x) = x_i x_j x_k M_{ijk}$$

Is there a way to write higher order moments in terms of lower order moments, analogous to what Isserlis theorem does for the Gaussian?

Comment: This wikipedia section suggests that maybe the answer is no -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#A_negative_result

Comment: The $\mathbb{R}$ version does not have finite integral. Do you mean $x_ix_jx_kx_lM_{ijkl}$?